# How do I download a release asset from GitLab via curl

Tags: curl, gitlab

Im trying to create a bash script to download a private release from GitLab using curl but it keeps getting redirected to the signin page.

How can I do this?

I have tried the following with no luck:

```
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: XXXXXXXXX" "https://gitlab.com/mrhid6/test/-/archive/v0.0.5/test-v0.0.5.zip"
```

Comment: I have updated with code i've tried.

Comment: That project might not exist. If private, using a private token does not work.

Answer (score 4):

As Win32Sector says, it is a [bug](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/28978), but the issue is open for quite a long time and it is constantly pushed to the next milestone...

As a workaround, you can use [Package Registry](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/) as a data store and then reference the package files from the Releases page, so that user does not recognize anything:

1. Enable Package registry - tick **Packages** in **Project -> Settings -> General -> Visibility, project features, permissions**.
2. Upload a package via [Package API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/packages.html):

```
 curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: ####" --upload-file /local/file/asset-file.txt https://<your.gitlab.instance>/api/v4/projects/<PROJECT>/packages/generic/<PACKAGE_NAME>/<VERSION>/asset-file.txt
```

3. Add a link to the Releases page using [Releases API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/releases/):

```
curl --request POST --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: ####" --data name="My asset name" --data link_type="package" --data url="https://<your.gitlab.instance>/api/v4/projects/<PROJECT>/packages/generic/<PACKAGE-NAME>/<VERSION>/asset-file.txt" "https://<your.gitlab.instance>/projects/<PROJECT>/releases/<VERSION>/assets/links"
```

4. Then download your asset either by clicking the link in GitLab (the user is already logged in) or using access token and Packages API:

```
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: ####" "https://<your.gitlab.instance>/api/v4/projects/<PROJECT>/packages/generic/<PACKAGE-NAME>/<VERSION>/asset-file.txt"
```

Answer (score 3):

Gitlab said it is bug =(

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/62307

I want to download assets too.

Answer (score -2):

You cannot use the Private token to access the repository zip file like that.

Check https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/repositories.html#get-file-archive, you should be using this:

```
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <your_access_token>" https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/mrhid6%2Ftest/repository/archive.zip
```

Comment: This download the archive of the repo, not the asset.