# How to upload a compressed file (zip) to the assets of a concrete release in Gitlab and using curl

Tags: curl, gitlab, gitlab-api

Within my repository, i have created a release based on a tag:
[image]

Now using a curl command i am trying to upload to the release assets a compressed zip file called DemoFile.zip using below curl command:

```
curl --request POST --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <my token>" --form "file=@demoFile.zip" "https://my.gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<my project id>/uploads"
```

I am executing the above curl command from the same folder where demoFile.zip is.

I get the following response:

```
{"alt":"demoFile.zip","url":"/uploads/<an alpahnumeric number>/demoFile.zip","full_path":"/myName/myProjectName/uploads/<same alphanumeric number>/demoFile.zip","markdown":"[demoFile.zip](/uploads/<same alphanumeric number>/demoFile.zip)"}
```

Then when I check in Gitlab from Deployments-->Releases i cannot see demoFile.zip under assets:

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is a bug in Gitlab, commented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56329436/1624552):

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/62307

I finally succedeed to make it work but through package registry, i mean, put a package there and then link it in the release created as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66442444/1624552).